# How to make a target depend on another target's QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS

Tags: qt, qmake

My project has top-level directory `proj` with subdirectories `runtime` and `test`. Basically, `test` depends on `runtime`, but it's a little more complicated.

**Expected behavior**: If you modify a file in `runtime`, then make `runtime`, then make `test`, this should rebuild `test`.

**Actual behavior**: For `test`, you get "make: Nothing to be done for `first'."

Here are the relevant excerpts from the project files.

proj.pro:

```
test.depends = runtime
```

runtime.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG = no_link target_predeps staticlib
TARGET =

# Avoid building libruntime.a
QMAKE_AR_CMD = @true
QMAKE_RANLIB = @true

include(../proj.pri)

RUNTIME_SOURCES += \
    foo.c
    bar.c
```

proj.pri:

```
CLANG_RUNTIME_FLAGS = -emit-llvm
runtime.input = RUNTIME_SOURCES
runtime.output = lib${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}.bc
runtime.commands = $$CLANG $$CLANG_RUNTIME_FLAGS -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += runtime
```

In `runtime`'s Makefile, there is a rule for target `compiler_runtime_make_all` that seems to correspond to the `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS`. The files built by this rule (foo.bc and bar.bc) are in the `OBJECTS` list, so they get built when you make this Makefile.

In `test`'s Makefile, there is also a rule for target `compiler_runtime_make_all`, but it has no recipe and it's not referred to anywhere.

So how do I tell `test` that it should depend on the `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS` for `runtime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top-level `proj.pro` (which I assume is [`TEMPLATE = subdirs`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#template)), specifying that `test` depends on `runtime` *only* affects the order in which the top-level `make` is run on the specified `SUBDIRS`.  It does *not* introduce any additional dependencies in any of the subdirectories — those are all totally independent invocations of `qmake` and `make`.

So, to solve this, you'll need to have `test.pro` indicate the specific `runtime` files it depends on.  See the [`POST_TARGETDEPS`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#post-targetdeps) variable.

Or if you're using [`QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS`](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Custom_tools) to build the sources in `test.pro`, you could add something like this:

```
test.depends = $${ROOT}/runtime/lib*.bc
```